# show only log inserted by user

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

i am using slf4j to log information , using spark and scala.How can i display message inserted by user as logg not the whole spark log file , here is log4j.properties

```
# Here we have defined root logger
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,R


#Direct log messages to file
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=./logging.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p  %c{1}:%L- %m%n
```

and here example  of what is shown by spark

```
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@7eac9008
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@4116aac9
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@62ddbd7e
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 16
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 16
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  PooledByteBufAllocator:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@ae13544
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3d34d211
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@7dc0f706
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@4009e306
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@43c1b556
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@587e5365
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@22fcf7ab
2017-08-29 09:19:03 TRACE  NioEventLoop:46- Instrumented an optimized java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@2de23121
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  ThreadLocalRandom:71- -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0x7436749e963a1485 (took 1 ms)
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  ByteBufUtil:76- -Dio.netty.allocator.type: unpooled
2017-08-29 09:19:03 DEBUG  ByteBufUtil:76- -Dio.netty.t

 i want to see only message inserted by user
```

Here the scalla code

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

Comment: please check the update , i used the same as you , there are less information in the log but still unuseful information